# augmented reality object has sound when target found what i need is how to repeat that sound I

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have an augmented reality mobile application wherein a sound automatically plays for a specific image target and it stops when the target is lost. What I need is how do I repeat the sound by using a button while still focusing on that image target.

Example:

```
          Image target - Apple 
          Sound - Letter A sound

         Image target- Banana
         Sound - Letter B sound
```

When I focus on the image target of apple, the letter A sound plays. How do i repeat that sound with the use of a button so I don't have to focus on the image target again.

Comment: how about calling the [PlayOneShot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) method from a [Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you want to have only one button repeating the last sound or do you want to have multiple buttons, one for each letter? And where is your code you have so far?

Comment: I want to have only one button.

Comment: I placed my code in DefaultTrackableHandle. This is the function to play sound.                                           
void playSound(string ss)
{
clipTarget = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(ss);
soundTarget.clip = clipTarget;
soundTarget.loop = false;
soundTarget.playOnAwake = false;
soundTarget.Play();
}

Comment: Then under DefaultTrackableHandle I have this. if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "letterA")
{
playSound("sounds/airplane");
}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways on how to do this

Usually you would have a component with a public method like

```
public class SoundController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // here you reference your Scene's AudioSource in the inspector 
    // e.g. via drag and drop
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource _audioSource;

    // Here you reference the according AudioClips
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip _letterASound;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip _letterBSound;

    // an enum makes it esier to find the correct letter later 
    public enum Letter
    {
        A,
        B
        // etc
    }

    // store the current Sound to be played
    public Letter CurrentLetter;

    private Button _button;

    // a dictionary makes it easy to find the according sound for a specific letter
    private Dictionary<Letter, AudioClip> _sounds;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // initialize the dictionary
        _sounds = new Dictionary<Letter, AudioClip>()
        {
            {A, _lettarASound},
            {B, _letterBSound}
        }

        // get the Button component
        _button = GetComponent<Button>();

        // add an onclick callback for the button
        // (it is save to allways first remove the callback to avoid double calls)
        _button.onClick.RemoveListener(PlayCurrentSound);
        _button.onClick.AddListener(PlayCurrentSound);
    }

    // make it public so you could even call it from somewhere else if needed
    public void PlayCurrentSound()
    {
        AudioSource.PlayOneShot(_sounds[CurrentLetter]);
    }
}
```

put this on the button next to the `Button` component and reference the `AudioSource` and `AudioClip`s (ofcourse you can add more if needed).

Now all thats left is to change the `CurrentLetter` everytime you hover over a new letter item. I don't know how your code looks for this but you would add something like

```
// here you will have to reference again in the inspector the
// SoundController component from above
[SerializeField] private SoundController _soundController;

// ....

// than whereever you have your code for
// "... plays for a specific image target and it stops when the target is lost ..."
// you add the line like e.g. for letter A
SoundController.CurrentLetter = SoundController.Letter.A;
```

so the next time you press the button it plays the sound for A.

Comment: im having problems with    AudioSource.PlayOneShot(_sounds[CurrentLetter]);

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on that?